# creating a web-page in my web-app that is accessible only to me

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, admin, security

In my web application I want to create a web-page accessible only to me. Through that page I want to upload photos and other data to my web-app/website. What should I do so that a particular web-page is accessible only to me ?

One way which I think is, reaching that web-page *(the page from where I will upload)* through another web-page that needs password authentication. But is this the only way and is it a good method ? The authentication will be through a servlet,in case I opt this method .

Comment: are u using tomcat? Or glassfish? What type of authentication you currently have in your app?

Comment: @Andrei D google app engine now.

Comment: Whoops, no experience in that area :) Maybe this will help you: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview

Answer (score 1):

If you could password protect it, You would only the person who can access that page,

To stop attacks you could also make that page orphan and put it at some weird path so that only you know the path to that page

put `Filter` specific to that page to check for authenticated session

Comment: Please re read the answer, and if you don't get the answer please comment (don't downvote)

Answer (score 0):

hash+salt your client name or some unique long number. check it on the server side.

make your app your password and credentials.

Comment: didn't understand your answer.

Comment: from what i understood, you're making an application for personal use to upload stuff on your website, right?

so, it's natural to somewhat presume that it won't be shared much. in which case you can hardcode all authentication stuff inside your app and save yourself the trouble of always having to input your password for your private (hidden) website. so for example you could make the page so that it only opens for your app. if, however the app is for broader audiences then this answer can be scrapped.